# Showing that a binary operation is smooth

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

With all the definitions of 'smooth' I'm not quite sure which one is important to Lie groups.

To understand the smoothness that is important to Lie groups, I've been told that the binary operation on $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$(x_1.x_2,x_3).(y_1,y_2,y_3)=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3+x_1y_2)$$

is a smooth operation. I have no idea where to start on showing that this is smooth. The same goes for maps with Lie groups and smooth manifolds.

Comment: All of the definitions of smooth (that I know) are equivalent. So showing any of them is good enough. Which book (or books?) are you using?

Comment: Smoothness usually requires some amount of differentiability.  So a place to **start** is to look at each of the six derivatives of this multiplication operation and see if the operation is at least once differentiable with respect to each of $x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3$.